# Draw rotating lines in pictureBox

Tags: c#, picturebox, flicker

I want to draw a rotating animation of a line inside a `PictureBox`. I use `pictureBox1.CreateGraphics()` to draw the line but I heard that this method is not suitable for `PictureBox`. Also, I'm experiencing heavy flickering on the `PictureBox` windows, any suggestion? Here is a code segment:

```
    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (comport.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                X = comport.ReadByte();
                Y = comport.ReadByte();
                Z = comport.ReadByte();
            }

            Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            Pen red = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
            g.TranslateTransform(100, 80 - X);
            g.RotateTransform(120);
            g.DrawLine(red, new Point(100, 0 + X), new Point(100, 80 - X));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            timer1.Interval = 1;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move your drawing code in the pictureBox1.Paint event handler and just call pictureBox1.Invalidate whenewer you need to redraw your pictureBox1. This is the real way how to draw. At the moment you are having flickering because you redraw your pictureBox1 on every second but you don't have primitives to draw at that moment.

```
        byte X;
        byte Y;
        byte Z;
        private void OnTimedEvent(object source, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (comport.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    X = comport.ReadByte();
                    Y = comport.ReadByte();
                    Z = comport.ReadByte();
                }
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                timer1.Interval = 1;
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Pen red = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
            g.TranslateTransform(100, 80 - X);
            g.RotateTransform(120);
            g.DrawLine(red, new Point(100, 0 + X), new Point(100, 80 - X));
        }
```

Comment: One more thing, if I want to draw a line in the pictureBox without clearing the existing line, what should I do?

Comment: There are two possible approaches. If you want to draw finite number of lines you can store each new value of X into a List or Array (I prefer lists because they can grow lot easier) and when have enough values (lets say 10-20) than you should add new values and remove the oldest ones. Then on every Paint event you should iterate through  those values and draw lines. The other method can be drawing on a Bitmap each new line without clearing old ones, but eventually the bitmap will be overloaded with lines and picture won't have any sense. If you want more clarification I'm available.